# compute with neural network in R?

Tags: r, neural-network

all tuples in allClassifiers tuples are either 1 or 2 
e.g.

```
    naiveBayesPrediction    knnPred5    knnPred10   dectreePrediction   logressionPrediction    correctClass
    1                       2                1           1                     1                          1
    1                       2                1           1                     1                          1
    1                       2                1           1                     1                          1
    1                       2                1           2                     1                          1
```

I trained the ensembler

```
ensembleModel <- neuralnet(correctClass ~ naiveBayesPrediction + knnPred5 + knnPred10 + dectreePrediction + logressionPrediction, data=allClassifiers[ensembleTrainSample,])
```

but I am trying to use it to predict with this:

```
compute(ensembleModel, allClassifiers[ensembleTestSample,])$net.result
```

but I get this error:

> Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : non-conformable arguments

my train and Test samples

```
ensembleTrainSample <- sample(nrow(allClassifiers), nrow(allClassifiers)*0.7)
ensembleTestSample <- (1:nrow(allClassifiers))[!(1:nrow(allClassifiers))%in% ensembleTrainSample]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to your other question this is an error the stems from matrix multiplication.  In essence, the following error:

> Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : non-conformable arguments

means that your matrices don't have dimensions that match for matrix multiplication.  It's like trying to multiply a 4x4 matrix by a 10x10 matrix.  it simply isn't going to work.

Now the reason you are getting this error is because you overlooked something in the documentation.  If you look at `?compute` you will see the following note about the `covariate` argument`:

```
covariate   a dataframe or matrix containing the variables 
            that had been used to train the neural network.
```

The key here is **VARIABLES**, not your entire dataset nor the classifier variable (you are trying to predict this!).  Here is an example again with the `infert` dataset.

```
library(neuralnet)
data(infert)

# fit your neuralnet model
net.infert <- neuralnet(case~parity+induced+spontaneous, infert)

net.pred <- compute(net.infert, infert[,c("case","parity","induced","spontaneous")])
```

> Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : non-conformable arguments

But if I just include the variables I used to create the model it works without error.

```
# no error
net.pred <- compute(net.infert, infert[,c("parity","induced","spontaneous")])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :) ive updated my question do I need to change my test sample without the correctClass or something?

Comment: Yes, you only want your test sample to include the variables you use to train the model.

Comment: sorry to keep bothering you,  Think your solution worked so thank you, I get a bunch of values like 1.4.. : 1.8... in a column and i want to know how I can calculate how accurate it is? I made the test sample a table without the class like you said of [334: 505, 5]

Comment: I assume your classes are 1 or 2.  As such, your output is the models estimate of that value.  The simplest approach is to simply `round` the values.  Otherwise you would need to start looking in to probability statistics (e.g. bayesian).